# Simulink: What happens when subsystems are initialized?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've been having a lot of trouble getting simulink's block callbacks to run, and the documentation is woefully inadequate and disorganized. It seems that I'm misunderstanding multiple points of how Simulink compiles models, but since StackOverflow dislikes multi-part questions, I will post them one at a time.

**The situation**: I have a library of components, each of which is a virtual subsystem whose parameters are defined through the masks. Block `A` has Parameter `a` which is sent to the base workspace using the 'assignin' command.

Next, the block `B` has a parameter `b` which is initialized in the Initialization tab of the mask.

Finally, the StartFcn callback of the block `B` runs a *script* which needs to reference both `a` and `b` to calculate `c`. In the script, I reference `a` simply as `a` because it's in the 'base' workspace, and I reference `b` using `get_param(gcb,'b')`.

Now, this last command works when the parameter `b` is a user input (so it's a constant value). But in my case, this `b` is calculated using *other* parameters in the Initialization tab. And for some reason, in the script, this parameter is always zero.

I added a display within the block `B` to see what these values are, and they are clearly non-zero.

Can someone please explain why the script cannot seem to get the real value of the areas out of the block?

Comment: What do you mean by "the block B has a parameter b", is it a mask parameter? If 'b' is *not* a masked parameter and you only have it in the Mask Initialization, then I would guess its only local to the mask, it's not an actual parameter of the block that you can get with get_param.

Comment: Hi @pmb, yes, it is a mask parameter. However, the parameter is not a user input. It is calculated in the initialization tab. Which means that, according to what you say, I cannot access `b` unless it's a user input. However, I still *am* able to use `b` in constants *within* the subsystem. Could you tell me why it works within the system but not when I try to get it using the `get_param`?

Comment: If it is a masked parameter, meaning you have entered it in the Parameters & Dialog tab and unchecked the "visibility" so that the user can't input it, then I have no explanation.

Comment: Only the masked parameters can be accessed with get_param, if you just have "b = 1+1" in the initialization tab, this is *not* gettable with get_param because it is only local to that tab. This is not considered a mask parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you should really be using [getworkspacevariables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.mask.getworkspacevariables.html)

Comment: @pmb Thanks for your help. You're right, that is exactly what I did. And I've sort of reconciled with not being able to get it out from there. Now, I send that data to the base workspace, read it, and then clear it from the workspace. Inelegant, but works. I just don't know WHY it won't work. It's a parameter. It's useable WITHIN that subsystem. It's NOT useable from a script accessing the system. Why? I can't find out.

Comment: Check out Phil Goddard's link. Its what you need to access "b" without making it a mask parameter. I learned something new :)

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Could you make that into an answer so I can accept it? Or should I answer it myself. Anyway, for others reading this, the trick is to do what the documentation says: `vars = Simulink.Mask.get('model/blockName').getWorkspaceVariables` and this gives you a structure `vars` with all the values. Then, `vars(1,20).Value` for example, will give you the numerical value of the 20th element in the subsystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the masked workspace variable using [getworkspacevariable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.mask.getworkspacevariables.html)